# Legal requirements when launching a video streaming service

Tags: legal

I'm about to launch an app in which the users can transmit the screen of their android phones and then see it in a browser. It is used mainly for demonstrations. It also transmits the audio captured by the microphone.

This audio and video are broadcasted through a media server which I have to contract.

My questions are regarding about legal aspects that I am worried about:

1. What happens if any user transmitted content with copyright, like videos from Netflix, Youtube, etc... will I be responsible for that? How can I protect myself against that?
2. What happens if any user transmitted illegal content, like pornography, aggressions...? I have to take any legal protection against this?

Any help will be highly appreciated,
Thanks.

Comment: You need to hire an attorney, not ask a bunch of other freelancers.

Comment: This will depend upon jurisdiction, so cannot be answered here.  You could look at https://law.stackexchange.com/ to see if it is on-topic there, but you will have to state your jurisdiction.

Comment: This would be closed as off-topic for asking for specific legal advice on Law.SE. I think that unless we have an industry expert, this will also be off topic for Freelancing, due to not being able to answer it specifically and correctly

Comment: I guess it might help if you include a country or list of potential countries to look at - the EU's privacy laws are different compared to say (most of) the US' so a more targeted scope would be required